# Load process definitions from multiple modules in camunda

Tags: java, spring, bpmn, multi-module, camunda

I'm trying to configure Camunda automatic resource deployment for a multimodule project. What I want to archive is that for the following project structure:

```
\---learnCamunda
|   pom.xml
+---application
|   |   pom.xml
|   +---src
|       \---main
|           +---java
|           |   \---com
|           |       \---camunda
|           |            \---learnCamunda
|           |               |   LearnCamundaApplication.java
|           |               \---configuration
|           |                       CustomOracleDialect.java
|           |                       FlywayConfiguration.java
|           |                       H2ConsoleConfiguration.java                 
|           \---resources
|               |   application.properties
|               |   
|               \---processes
|                       loanRequest.bpmn                      
+---contract-management
   |   pom.xml 
   \---src
      \---main
          +---java
          |   \---com
          |       \---camunda
          |           \---learnCamunda
          |               +---dto
          |               +---dts
          |               +---entity
          |               \---enums
          \---resources
              \---processes
                      DUMMY_PROCESS.bpmn
```

where `application` and `contract management` are modules of `learnCamunda` project, I want my `application.properties` to provide classpath for Camunda resource scan to pickup both `loanRequest.bpmn` and `DUMMY_PROCESS.bpmn`. Is that possible via `application.properties` in application module? (The application module has dependency on contract-management module)

If it is possible then which camunda property -- should I set it and to what?

I have already tried different combinations of `deployment-resource-pattern` but non of them worked.

**EDIT:**
One thing i noticed is that `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findAllClassPathResources` loads all resources from target, my compiled model is in `target.classes.processes` and classpath resource from resolver is `target.classes` so it seems it's not done recursively, but im having hard time to confirm this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to be looking at the `deployment-resource-pattern` property as the place to start. By default, it will include `classpath*:**/*.bpmn` so your file should be loaded.

That suggests the problem is either the value of `deployment-resource-pattern` has been changed or the contract-management jar is not on the classpath.

I suggest you try debugging the app to check the value of `camunda.deployment-resource-pattern`. Then have a look at the build process and make sure your application depends on contract-management, its the same version and the parent pom is building both of them.

Comment: i have verified that module application has contract-management in classpath, both application and contract-management are defined as modules in parent pom, versioning matches and parent is indeed building both of them. I have removed property `deployment-resource-pattern` to use default but this did not help. i Have checked `DefaultDeploymentConfiguration` and resource patters are correct. Also im having my doubs about where tha camunda dependency should be. Currently dependency is in contract-management, is this correct?

Comment: after long debugging session, it turns out that you were partially right, the issue was with classpaths: module contract-management was not resolved in project classpath for som reason, i have reorganized pom structures and now it works like a charm